# Простой цикл для радио-кнопок

Tags: php, циклы

Есть таблица с офисами (может быть 1 или 100 офисов).
Для каждого офиса можно выбрать одну из трех опций, нажав на радио-кнопку.
Что мне нужно, так это раздать имена кнопкам, чтобы у первого офиса радио-кнопки были с именем price-1, у второго price-2 и так далее.

```
<tr>
  <td>Office 1</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="price-1"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="price-1"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="price-1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Office 2</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="price-2"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="price-2"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="price-2"></td>
</tr>

...

<tr>
  <td>Office n</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="price-n"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="price-n"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="price-n"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $count = 100;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; ++$i): ?>

<tr>
  <td>Office <?= $i; ?></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="price-<?= $i; ?>"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="price-<?= $i; ?>"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="price-<?= $i; ?>"></td>
</tr>

<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: напишите и про value уж тогда

Comment: @splash58 value что?

Comment: вы не думаете, что  след. вопрос будет: как понять, какая опция выбрана  ? :)