# Пройтись циклом по radio button name'ам

Tags: php

У меня есть таблица со всеми офисами и напротив каждого офиса 3 радио кнопки. Само собой, каждому радио нужно задать одинаковое имя, для своего офиса. В моем случае имя должно быть `price-1`, `price-2` ... `price-n`. Нужны именно числовые значения, так как на них уже завязан js.

Офисов может быть как один, так и тысяча, поэтому и нужно найти динамическое решение. Пробовал само собой циклом пройтись, но мои знания еще слишком скудны, он мне множит все тдшки и в итоге вместо 4 офисов (в моем примере массив на 4 офиса), получаю 4 офиса помноженных на 4. Вот сам код:

```
<table>
    <?php $offices = array("Office_1", "Office_2", "Office_3", "Office_4") ?>
    <?php if (!empty($offices)){ ?>
        <?php foreach ($offices as $id => $office) { ?>
            <tr>
                <?php for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++) { ?>
                    <td><?php echo $office; ?></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="price-<?php echo $i; ?>" checked></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="price-<?php echo $i; ?>"></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="price-<?php echo $i; ?>"></td>
                <?php } ?>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: А это не вы случаем спрашивали? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496687/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA/

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Может быть так:

```
<table>
    <?php $offices = array("Office_1", "Office_2", "Office_3", "Office_4") ?>
    <?php if (!empty($offices)) { ?>
        <?php foreach ($offices as $id => $office) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $office; ?></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="price-<?php echo $id; ?>" checked></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="price-<?php echo $id; ?>"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="price-<?php echo $id; ?>"></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Если я Вас правильно понял, Вы хотите чтобы напротив названия офиса Office_id было три радио-кнопки price-office_id.

Comment: Код неверный. У вас в каждом столбце по три одинаковых radiobutton.

Comment: Почему же? Если это, например, три колонки прайс-листа, то имя у радиобаттон должно быть одно, а значения разные

Comment: Хм, вы правы. Подождем, что скажет сам автор, угадали ли вы его потребность.

Comment: Спасибо! Вы очень правильно меня поняли. Именно это и нужно было, увидев ваше решение сразу понял в чем дело.
Есть только еще один вопрос. Возможно ли установить в данном случае отсчет не с 0, а с 1?

Comment: А как вы собираетесь в обработчике определять какие радиобаттоны какому офису принадлежат? Если с этим проблемы нет, то перед <tr> добавьте строку <?php $r_id = $id+1;?> и, соответственно, у радиобаттонов поменяйте переменную с $id на $r_id

Comment: Спасибо, теперь как раз все как надо.

Comment: @Dubo Пожалуйста, не публикуйте благодарности отдельным ответом. Вместо этого отметьте верный ответ зеленой галочкой (слева от ответа).